# How to make content delay using CSS and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am attempting to create a page where the content on the screen appears 3 seconds after the page loads. By the other posts I have seen on this website, I attempted the scripting below, though with no success (Everything appears at the same time).

First is the section I am attempting to delay, then is the whole pages script. Any guidance is very much appreciated. (I am hoping I am wording everything correctly this time so I don't get another -1)

Section to delay:

```
    <div class="content">
                  <div id="fade">
                    <h1>Main Text</h1>
                    <h3>Secondary Text</h3>
                    <a href="#about" class="btn">Read More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </section>
    
    
    <style>#fade p {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-top: 25px;
        font-size: 21px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    
    <script>
    <$("#fade p").delay(3000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
    </script>
```

And here is the entire page

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    </head>
    
    <body bgcolor="#000000" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    
    
    
    
    
    <section class="showcase"> 
    <div class="video-container">
                    <video src="https://traversymedia.com/downloads/video.mov" autoplay muted loop></video>
                </div>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
                <div class="content">
                  <div id="fade">
                    <h1>Main Text</h1>
                    <h3>Secondary Text</h3>
                    <a href="#about" class="btn">Read More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </section>
    
    
    <style>#fade p {
        opacity: 0;
        margin-top: 25px;
        font-size: 21px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    </style>
    
    <script>
    <$("#fade p").delay(3000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700);
    </script>
    
    
    
    
    <style>
    
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400&display=swap');
    
    :root {
        --primary-color: #3a4052;
    }
    
    * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    body {
        font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
    a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color: var(--primary-color);
    }
    
    h1 {
        font-weight: 300;
        font-size: 60px;
        line-height: 1.2;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
    }
    
    .showcase {
        height: 100vh;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    
    .video-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: var(--primary-color) url('./https://traversymedia.com/downloads/cover.jpg') no-repeat center
            center/cover;
    }
    
    .video-container video {
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
      position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .video-container:after {
        content: '';
        z-index: 1;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    .content {
        z-index: 2;
    }
    
    .btn {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 10px 30px;
        background: var(--primary-color);
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: solid #fff 1px;
        margin-top: 25px;
        opacity: 0.7;
    }
    
    .btn:hover {
        transform: scale(0.98);
    }
    
    #about {
        padding: 40px;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    #about p {
        font-size: 1.2rem;
        max-width: 600px;
        margin: auto;
    }
    
    #about h2 {
        margin: 30px 0;
        color: var(--primary-color);
    }
    
    .social a {
        margin: 0 5px;
    }
    
    </style>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: you have no #fade p element within your html. Try just '#fade'

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately that didn't work though

Comment: you have a extra < in this part $("#fade p").delay(3000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700); here. Also, there is no p tag so you need to target just #fade in your css and the jquery selectors. Lastly, your not including the jquery library. You need to add the reference in your head tag.

Comment: Thank you for the help. None of those resolved it, though I appreciate the comments. I posted the answer to make it work however I changed it all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I ended up changing it all to, to make it work. Hopefully this will help others that are looking to do this.

```css
.content {
  -webkit-animation: 3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
  animation: 3s ease 0s normal forwards 1 fadein;
}

@keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fadein {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  66% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@300;400&display=swap');
 :root {
  --primary-color: #3a4052;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 60px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.showcase {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 0 20px;
}

.video-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: var(--primary-color) url('./https://traversymedia.com/downloads/cover.jpg') no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.video-container video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  object-fit: cover;
}

.video-container:after {
  content: '';
  z-index: 1;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
}

.content {
  z-index: 2;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: var(--primary-color);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: solid #fff 1px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.btn:hover {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

#about {
  padding: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}

#about p {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: auto;
}

#about h2 {
  margin: 30px 0;
  color: var(--primary-color);
}

.social a {
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="showcase">
  <div class="video-container">
    <video src="https://traversymedia.com/downloads/video.mov" autoplay muted loop></video>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <h1>Main Text</h1>
    <h3>Secondary Text</h3>
    <a href="#about" class="btn">Read More</a>
  </div>
</section>
```